# Computing $\int \frac{7x}{(2x+1)} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to compute the following integral $$\int \frac{7x}{(2x+1)} dx$$
Unfortunately Wolfram Alpha gives me a different result, but other integral calculators say that my result is correct. So where is my error:

$$\int \frac{7x}{(2x+1)} dx = \frac{7}{2}\int \frac{2x}{(2x+1)} dx$$
$$\frac{7}{2}\int \frac{2x+1}{(2x+1)} - \frac{1}{(2x+1)} dx = \frac{7}{2}\int 1 dx - \int \frac{1}{(2x+1)} dx$$
Let $u=2x+1$
$$=\frac{7}{2}(x-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u}du)=\frac{7x}{2}-\frac{7}{4}\ln(|2x+1|)+C$$
Wolfram Alpha tells me that it is $$\frac{7}{4} (2 x - \ln(2 x + 1) + \underbrace{1}_{different}) + C$$
Why is there an additional $1$?

Comment: It doesn't matter since this is a constant term which can be "hidden" or "absorbed" by the integration constant $C$. It might happen that sometime constants pop up when computing integral with different method but in the end it doesn't matter.

Comment: As general advice for indefinite integration problems, the answer should be "checked" by differentiation.  Thinking about it that way makes it clear why "an additional $1$" in the result does not affect the result's correctness.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why was this voted off-topic? I think it is a reasonably asked question.

Comment: Now a good question would be why WolframAlpha has the +1 when it already has +C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $C$ is an **arbitrary constant**, so both answers are actually correct. One may thus let $k=\frac{7}{4}+C$ and then obtain the same answer you've obtained.

Comment: Damn you had an answer before I even had time to click "1 new question available". +1

Comment: @mrnovice There was a blog post about these users.  We call them 'gunslingers' ;)

Comment: That is some way too fast "projectile motion" for my typing speed :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But what if the integral would be indefinite. Would I still obtain the same result the way I did it, when comparing to Wolfram Alpha (implying there was no error in my computation)?

Comment: The integral you've mentioned is indefinite.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at what Wolfram gives you

$$\frac{7}{4} (2 x - \ln(2 x + 1) +1 )+ C$$

and see that you have an "extra" term, look at it this way: any constant terms that differ from your result may have been "absorbed" into the arbitrary constant.

What you get is *an* antiderivative, the important thing when you evaluate indefinite integrals is that you can get back to the original integrand when you take the derivative of your result.

Answer (score 0):

> If $y=F(x)$ be a primitive of the function $y=f(x)$ then for every real $k$ the function $y=F(x)+k$ is a primitive also.

The primitive of $\dfrac{7x}{2x+1}$ is $\dfrac{7}{4} (2x -\ln(2 x + 1))$, then for every real $k$ the function $y=\dfrac{7}{4} (2x -\ln(2 x + 1))+k$ is a primitive also.